# MongoDB using $set

Tags: mongodb

If I have the following document:
{ _id: 1, name: "Alto", color: "Red",cno: "H410",speed:40,mfdcountry: "India"}

If i issue below two commands . What is the difference?

```html
Case1:
db.car.findAndModify({
query: { name: "Alto" },
update: { speed: 20, color: "Yellow" }
})

Case2:
db.car.findAndModify({
query: { name: "Alto" },
update: {$set:{ speed: 20, color: "Yellow" }}
})
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use the the first update command the document will be updated but the fields you didn't include in the update statement will be unset. The result would look something like this:

```
 { _id: 1, color: "Yellow", speed:20}
```

In the second scenario, using $set, the fields specified will be updated and the other left unchanged. This would be the result

```
 { _id: 1, name: "Alto", color: "Yellow",cno: "H410",speed:20,mfdcountry: "India"}
```

Comment: Great thanks!! I am just starting to learn MongoDB. I know this is a noob question

Answer (score 1):

Case1 will change the whole document, except _id.

```
    `{ "_id" : 1, "speed" : 20, "color" : "Yellow" }`
```

Case2 will only change the properties in $set.

```
    `{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Alto", "color" : "Yellow", "cno" : "H410", "speed" : 20, "mfdcountry" : "India" }`
```